# Centreing a Graphic Object in java

Tags: java, graphics

Hello i'm currently working on a 2D Game Engine written entirely in java. Is there a way to centre a Graphics Object (g.drawString(x,y,z).

It would be preferably if this could be done through Graphics and the DefaultToolkit.

Thankyou very much :)

Comment: Start by taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284754/java-center-text-in-rectangle/14287270#14287270)

Comment: string are measured by points, while you draw with pixels, and there is no way to draw a string in pixels, but you would get the drawn string in pixel and draw it at the center

Comment: Yes you could center a graphics object. What are you trying to achieve here. `g.drawString(x,y,z)` does it for you. You need to if other objects could be centered aswell?

Comment: So if i use g.drawString(x,y,z) and for example y (x axis) is 40, would the start of the text be located at 40px or would the centre of the text be at 40px?

Answer (score 1):

Simple mathematics. We have the object to be centered and the area where it should be centered.

Object width - w

Object height - h

Area width - aW

Area height - aH

//Follow center coordinates are coordinates where top left corner should be placed in order for the object to lie in center

centerWidth = (aW - W) /2

centerHeight = (aH - H) /2

As you can see, you MUST know the metrics of area you are placing your object on !
If that area is just the screen, then screen dimension can be used like this.

```
    //Some dummy object metrics
    int w = 30;
    int h = 60;

    //Now we find out the area metrics
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int aW = screenSize.width;
    int aH = screenSize.height;

    //Apply our common formula
    int centerWidth = (aW - w) / 2;
    int centerHeight = (aH - h) /2;
```

This works well for objects you know (their width and height).

**Text centering**

If you want to center text, you can use [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) class, which allows you to measure size of text.