# Centering String in Panel

Tags: java, swing, text, graphics, java-2d

I'm trying to center a String in a Panel.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
            int stringWidth = 0;
            int stringAccent = 0;
            int xCoordinate = 0;
            int yCoordinate = 0;
            // get the FontMetrics for the current font
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();


        /** display new message */
        if (currentMessage.equals(message1)) {
            removeAll();
            /** Centering the text */
            // find the center location to display
            stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message2);
            stringAccent = fm.getAscent();
            // get the position of the leftmost character in the baseline
            xCoordinate = getWidth() / 2 - stringWidth / 2;
            yCoordinate = getHeight() / 2 + stringAccent / 2;

            // draw String
            g.drawString(message2, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
            currentMessage = message2;  // alternate message
        }
}
```

Is there a single method I can use to simplify this task?

For example:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (currentMessage.equals(message1)) {
                removeAll();
                // draw String centered (with one line of code)
            }
}
```

Just seems like I'm doing a lot of work just to center text.

Comment: Putting the text in a label is 'simpler' as the label returns a preferred size..  E.G. as seen in [`LabelRenderTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/418556).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the java standard library? No, you can always do something along this

```
private void drawStringMiddleOfPanel(String string, Graphics g) {
            String message2 = string;
            int stringWidth = 0;
            int stringAccent = 0;
            int xCoordinate = 0;
            int yCoordinate = 0;
            // get the FontMetrics for the current font
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();


        /** display new message */
            /** Centering the text */
            // find the center location to display
            stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message2);
            stringAccent = fm.getAscent();
            // get the position of the leftmost character in the baseline
            xCoordinate = getWidth() / 2 - stringWidth / 2;
            yCoordinate = getHeight() / 2 + stringAccent / 2;

            // draw String
            g.drawString(message2, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
            currentMessage = message2;  // alternate message
        }
```

With

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (currentMessage.equals(message1)) {
            removeAll();
            drawStringMiddleOfPanel(message1, g);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like ...

```
xCoordinate = (getWidth() - stringWidth) / 2;
yCoordinate = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight) / 2) + stringAccent;
```

Instead.

Take a look at [Java center text in rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284754/java-center-text-in-rectangle/14287270#14287270) for additional details

Also, you could achieve the same thing using a `JLabel` on a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout`

**Updated**

Just noticed `removeAll();` in `paintComponent`.  This is not a good idea, as it can cause a new repaint request to posted to the event queue, putting your code into an infinte loop which could consume your CPU...

**Updated with example**

Side by side comparison of `drawString` and `JLabel`...(`drawString` on left, `JLabel` on right)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CenterText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CenterText();
    }

    public CenterText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                frame.add(new CenterStringPane());
                frame.add(new CenterLabelPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CenterStringPane extends ReferencePane {

        public CenterStringPane() {
            setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            String text = "In the center";
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();

            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class CenterLabelPane extends ReferencePane {

        public CenterLabelPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("In the center"));

        }
    }

    public class ReferencePane extends JPanel {

        public ReferencePane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int halfX = getWidth() / 2;
            int halfY = getHeight() / 2;
            g2d.drawLine(halfX, 0, halfX, getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine(0, halfY, getWidth(), halfY);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (currentMessage.equals(message1)) {
            removeAll();
            int x=  (panel.getWidth() / 2) - str.length()/2;
            int y = (panel.getHeight() / 2);
            graphics.drawString(str, x, y);

        }
   }
```