# Creating a string inside a Rectangle

Tags: java, string, swing, canvas

Hello i'm trying to do a string inside a rectangle to make custom menus in java I'm using a  canvas and doing the following method, but I can't seem to get it right!

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    g2d.setFont(font);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    FontMetrics fm = root.getFontMetrics(font);
    g2d.drawString(option, (int)getX() - fm.stringWidth(option)/2, (int) getY() + fm.getHeight());
    g2d.drawRect((int)getX() - fm.stringWidth(option)/2 - 20, (int) getY() - fm.getHeight() - 10, (int)getX() - fm.stringWidth(option)/2 + 40 , (int) getY() - fm.getHeight() + 10);
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: I can't center the string inside the rectangle

Comment: I was kinda just trying to get it around the string not to much wider, just the necessary to look like a button.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem you have is that you are using the components x/y position where the `Graphics` context is already translated so that `0x0` is the top/left corner of the component.

[image: Center Text]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawText();
    }

    public DrawText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
            render(g);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void render(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20);
            g2d.setFont(font);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            String option = "This is a test";

            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(option)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2);
            g2d.drawString(option, x, y + fm.getAscent());
            g2d.drawRect(
                            (int)x - 20, 
                            (int)y - 10, 
                            (int)fm.stringWidth(option) + 40, 
                            (int)fm.getHeight() + 20);
        }
    }

}
```

For example...

- [Centering String in Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565066/centering-string-in-panel/18565132#18565132)
- [Java center text in rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284754/java-center-text-in-rectangle/14287270#14287270)

**Updated...**

If, each menu item is printed within a single component, then the concept provided above should work.  If you are printing multiple items within a single component, you could use something like...

[image]

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    g2d.setFont(font);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

    String option = "This is a test";

    while (x < getWidth()) {

        while (y < getHeight()) {

            int width = fm.stringWidth(option);
            int height= fm.getHeight();

            g2d.drawString(option, x + 20, y + fm.getAscent() + 10);
            width += 40;
            height += 20;
            g2d.drawRect(
                            (int) x,
                            (int) y,
                            (int) width,
                            (int) height);

            x += width;
            y += height;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I continue to have have a doubt. In your code you print the "button" right in the middle of the screen, but I want to do it in different Positions and when I do that getX() with your code the button goes somewhere else.

Comment: With the limited example you provided, it's difficult to provide a more detailed example...if `getX` and `getY` are the methods of canvas, then you have a problem

Comment: Yes I already know what is, my X is already Game.Width/2 so I can't divide it by 2 again. Thank you so much!