# Java: g.drawString() width and height in pixels?

Tags: java, string, swing, graphics, fontmetrics

I used fontmetrics to determine the length and height of the String drawn to a jpanel but it gave me incorrect measurements.

The String I used was: "Hello World this is fantastic"

For example: a drew a string with the default font; according to the font metrics the dimensions were: height: 24; width: 224.

when I measured it, it was in fact 148 pixels long and 10 pixels in height. (basically by trial and error)

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(this.f);
int Ilength = fm.stringWidth("Hello World this is fantastic");
int Iheight = fm.getHeight();
System.out.println("height: " + Iheight + "; width: " + Ilength);
```

I am wondering if there is a formula or method in java that can provide the actual height and width of the string in pixels. Thanks!

Comment: Checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729944/java-how-to-visually-center-a-specific-string-not-just-a-font-in-a-rectangle/23730189#23730189

Comment: Did you set the font for the graphics before you drew the string? `g.setFont(f)`.

Comment: no. right now i havent set the font. im just using the default.

Comment: ah I changed it to Times New Roman and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Get the bounds of the `GlyphVector` instead, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556)..

Comment: Also consider [`TextLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20textlayout).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Try to use the method `getStringBounds(String,Graphics)` of your `FontMetrics` object.

```
public Rectangle2D bounds = fm.getStringBounds("Hello World this is fantastic", g);
int Ilength = (int)bounds.getWidth();
int Iheight = (int)bounds.getHeight();
```