# How to center a drawString in Java?

Tags: java, string, graphics

How can I center the text of a drawString in Java? I want it to that it can be centered along the screen dynamically, whether I change the height and width of the box or not. I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27711103/5068885)but I don't know how to use it. can someone explain?

Comment: The answer in that post has some well documented method.

Comment: What part of *"I don't know how to use it"* are you stuck on

Comment: `but I don't know how to use it. can someone explain?`. 1st copy the code, 2nd paste the code, 3rd see what happens when you compile it, 4th analyze it, if you're stuck and have an error in it, then post **your** [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Horizontally...

```
String text = "...";
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
```

## Vertically...

```
String text = "...";
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
```

Also demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565066/centering-string-in-panel/18565132#18565132)

Also have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)