# How to Perfectly center a String in a Center Jpanel

Tags: java, string, swing, layout, jpanel

I am drawing 2 Strings which the one include my Name, Middle-name, Surname and the other my Country i am creating them  in a paint Component which is located in a Center panel, however, I have tried many different ways and calculations to center that String but no one of them is working correctly with accuracy is their an accurate way ?  this is an example of calculations that i have tried so far

```
posX=((getWidth()-fm.stringWidth(phrase))/2);
posY= ((getHeight()-fm.getHeight())/2);
```

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859509/how-to-center-a-drawstring-in-java/32859632#32859632), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565066/centering-string-in-panel/18565132#18565132) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284754/java-center-text-in-rectangle/14287270#14287270)

Comment: *"however, I have tried many different ways and calculations to center that String but no one of them is working correctly with accuracy is their an accurate way ?"* - I'd be nice if you could provide a demonstration of it "not working" and contracts that with what you are attempting to achieve

Comment: Why are you doing custom painting? Use JLabels and an appropriate layout manager. The layout manager will look after centering all the components.

Answer (score 1):

Because text is rendered from the baseline up, you need to adjust the `y` position to take that into account:

```
posY = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
```

Otherwise you're centring the text about the baseline, instead of "absolutely"

This is demonstrated [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284754/java-center-text-in-rectangle/14287270#14287270)

You should also have a look at [Font Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fontconcepts.html) for more details