# Move the Anchor Point of drawString() to center - Java

Tags: java

So. Let's say i use drawString() to draw a, well, a string obviously. Is there any possible way that i can see the anchor point of that being the center of the string rather than the top-left corner? This would allow me to move the arrow in reation to the center.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question

Comment: Thanks, I am little low on coffee and little bit out of it. Hope that's better.

Comment: Yes and no, but it will screw with a lot of other things. Look into Graphics#translate and AffineTransform. Generally speaking you should work by calculating an offset value instead

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer. I saw your answer on another question similar to this. :) which was very informative so thankyou. However, i am unable to access the graphic object in this case because its under a private variable in another class which i am unfortunately unable to edit therefore making it a little difficult. Thanks anyhow though, learned so much. :)

Comment: How are you calling `drawString` thing?

Comment: I am assuming you meant then. But its through another method provided by the aforementioned class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I center Graphics.drawString() in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706197/how-can-i-center-graphics-drawstring-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706197/how-can-i-center-graphics-drawstring-in-java) should be able to help you.
A simple equation can get you the appropriate coordinates to simulate center aligned text.

Comment: If you think that the question is already answered on Stack Overflow please flag it as a duplicate instead of linking to it in an answer or copying the answer. And, even more important: your answer should always answer the question, even when any reference or link becomes invalid. At the moment it does not, so it is not a valid answer