# Displaying code inside rectangle in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, graphics

```
// Eine einfache grafische Benutzeroberfläche mit Swing
    //von der Zeile 3 bis zur Zeile 5; Impotieren von Bibliothek
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
     
     
    public class HelloGUI extends JFrame { //  public class HelloGui
        public HelloGUI (String title) {
        super(title);
            getContentPane().add("North",new JButton("Hello World"));
            setSize(400,400);
            setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        
        }
     
        
        public void paint (Graphics g) {
     
            /* Das Verwenden von pain Methode
            * Graphics ist ein Parameter 
            * in g ist das Parameter Graphics gespeichert 
            */
            String insideRect = "Hello World!";
            //this String should be displayed inside of the rectangel
        
            
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new HelloGUI("Hello World ");
        }
    }

0 Antworten
```

I want to write a simpl java gui App, which display the Strin "Hello world", but it is very important to me that "Hello world" must be inside a rectangle.
so used the method `g.drawRect()` to draw a rectangle and the method `g.drawString()` to display the String "Hello World!" or any other message.
The Code work , but Hello World is not displayed iside the reactangle.
Can anybody help me to display the string "Hello Wolrd!"inside the rectangle... I try it but it didn't work. that is my code! tnx
so here is a screenshot of my result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daWM5.jpg)

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your app.

Comment: Read [the documentation of Graphics.drawString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.lang.String,int,int)) carefully.  The second sentence says: “The baseline of the leftmost character is at position (x, y) in this graphics context's coordinate system.”

Comment: @Code-Apprentice hey tnx for respounding !! i did it !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you start by looking at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

When drawing text, text is drawn from the base line UP (that is, the `y` position represents the baseline and the (majority) of the text is drawn above it)

[image]

** From [Measuring Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)*

In order to draw text so that it appears to be drawn "below" the `y` position, you need to offset the `y` position by the `ascent` height of the font.

For example...

```
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
g2d.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.drawString(insideRect, x, y + fm.getAscent());
```

> But why not use `Font#getSize`?

`Font#getSize` *"Returns the point size of this Font"* (*from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html)*), the physical requirements of the font may differ based on the rendering workflow and is not a "true" measure of the physical height (or rendering properties) of the font.

You should also take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to get a better idea of how painting works in Swing and how you should be working with it, as you're going to end up with no end of issues with your current approach.

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String insideRect = "Hello World!";
            //this String should be displayed inside of the rectangel
            int x = 100;
            int y = 100;

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            g2d.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawString(insideRect, x, y + fm.getAscent());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to centre the text (horizontally and vertically) you need to understand the difference between "absolute" or "baseline" centring (on the vertical axis), that is, are you trying to centre the text based on its baseline or its overall height?  There is a subtle difference between the two

For example...

- [Java center text in rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284754/java-center-text-in-rectangle/14287270#14287270)
- [Java - How to visually center a specific string (not just a font) in a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729944/java-how-to-visually-center-a-specific-string-not-just-a-font-in-a-rectangle/23730104#23730104)

Answer (score 1):

Your `String` is actually inside the rectangle, in the upper left corner. However it doesn't take the font size into consideration. The code below should put the text within the borders of the rectangle:

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
 
        /* Das Verwenden von pain Methode
        * Graphics ist ein Parameter 
        * in g ist das Parameter Graphics gespeichert 
        */
        String insideRect = "Hello World!";
        //this String should be displayed inside of the rectangel
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        g.drawRect(100,100,200,200);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);

        // add an offset to y coordinate
        Font font = g.getFont();
        g.drawString(insideRect, x ,y + font.getSize());
    }
```

**Edit**: To center the text you should play with the height and width of you rectangle & text, changing the texts `x` and `y` coordinates. Below I created `widthOffset` and `heightOffset` based on the width/height of the rectangle & text:

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
 
        /* Das Verwenden von pain Methode
        * Graphics ist ein Parameter 
        * in g ist das Parameter Graphics gespeichert 
        */
        String insideRect = "Hello World!";
        //this String should be displayed inside of the rectangel
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        g.drawRect(100,100,200,200);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);

        // center the text inside the rectangle
        Font font = g.getFont();
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(new AffineTransform(), true, true);
        Rectangle2D textRectangle = font.getStringBounds(insideRect, frc);
        int textWidth = (int) textRectangle.getWidth();
        int textHeight = (int) textRectangle.getHeight();

        int widthOffset = 100 - textWidth/2; // 100 = rectangle width / 2
        int heightOffset = 100 + textHeight/2; // 100 = rectangle height / 2

        g.drawString(insideRect, x + widthOffset ,y + heightOffset);
    }
```

To run the snippet above you should also import:

```
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
```

Comment: I am greatfull to you !! It really works. @happy songs
I have still one question : Do you know how I put the text in the center of ther Reactangle ?

Comment: I edited the answer, check the code below **Edit**. To center the text you should play with `x` and `y` coordinates of your text inside the rectangle container.

Comment: Tnx a lot !! I really appreciate you !! @happy songs

Comment: Could you please explain why we use super(title)

Comment: Font.getSize is wrong.  FontMetrics.getAscent is right.  The font size is the total line height in points, not pixels.  A 10 point font has lines which are ¹⁰⁄₇₂ inches high;  how many pixels that requires depends on the screen’s dot pitch.