# How to set fonts to a string

Tags: java, string, graphics, fonts, draw

Is there a way to set fonts on a string, and then draw the string using graphics? I know you can do it on Jlabels, and Jtextfields, and J-other components, but is there a way to do it just on the string instead? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, check out [Graphics, Text API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/text.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [attributed strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html) an example of is

```
Font font = new Font("LucidaSans", Font.PLAIN, 14);
AttributedString atString= new AttributedString("Example text string");
atString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font);
graphic.drawString(atString.getIterator(),x,y);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, start by checking out the [Graphics, Text tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/text.html)

Basically, you can set the font using [`Graphics#setFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setFont(java.awt.Font)) and draw a `String` using [`Graphics#drawString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)).

Also see [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for how you can perform custom painting in Swing

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284754/java-center-text-in-rectangle/14287270#14287270)

## List available font names....

```
String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
for (String font : fonts) {
    System.out.println(font);
}
```

or

```
Font fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
for (Font font : fonts) {
    System.out.println(font);
}
```

You can manipulate a font's properties using one of the `Font#derive` methods...

```
 Font font = ...;
 Font bigger = font.derive(32f);
 Font bolder = font.derive(Font.BOLD);
 Font biggerAndBolder = font.derive(Font.BOLD, 32f);
```

Comment: I see. When you set the font, you put the fonts name. And in the font below, I spelled times new roman wrong, yet it doesn't show up as an error. Why? static Font f = new Font("Times New Roan",Font.BOLD,20);

Comment: Why should it?  If I recall correctly, the API has a fall back process, so if the font doesn't exist on the system, it falls back to common font instead

Comment: How do we know if the font exist on the API or not, then? Is there a full list of the available fonts somewhere? And how many contructors exist for creating fonts?

Comment: Something like `String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();`.  Have a look at [`GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts()) and [`GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAvailableFontFamilyNames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAvailableFontFamilyNames())

Comment: also. How am I suppose to use this? public abstract Font[] getAllFonts()

Comment: `String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();` ...

Comment: You do realise, getting a list of the available fonts was really part of the original question you asked ;)

Comment: See update (the original comment had additional unicode characters in it, which were screwing things up)

Answer (score 0):

We can actually set the font in graphics...and then draw the string.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.setFont(Fonts.f);
    g.drawString(Fonts.text, 50, 50);

}
```